# Hide keyboard when UIMenuViewController is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uimenucontroller

When i show `UIMenuViewController` on a `UITextFiled`, keyboard also pops up.

Wondering if there is a way to hide the keyboard when `UIMenuViewController` is visible.

I use the below code to show the menu.

```
    NSArray *buttons = items;
    NSMutableArray *menuItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *buttonText in buttons) {
        NSString *sel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"magic_%@", buttonText];
        [menuItems addObject:[[UIMenuItem alloc]
                              initWithTitle:buttonText
                              action:NSSelectorFromString(sel)]];
    }
    UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuCont setTargetRect:view.frame inView:view.superview];
    menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
    menuCont.menuItems = menuItems;
    [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: I suppose you could set up an observer to listen for `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` and then have a method called to `endEditing` on your views

Comment: @LouisTur I added [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(_textWillShowMenu:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil]; but how do i access the view in textWillShowMenu?

Comment: you can call any reference to the view that contains the text, or for example you can just call `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in the event you're using a `UIViewController`, calling the top level view will resignFirstResponder for all child views

Answer (score 0):

when you want to hide keyboard (in your example menu items are visible) for hiding keyboard use 
[textField resignFirstResponder];

May for that your problem will solve

Comment: resignFirstResponder will show a flick effect of keyboard just opening and closing.